# Is there a way I can generate MP table from ACPI tables?

Tags: c, unix, boot, platform, acpi

I am trying to fake mptable for a kernel that needs mptables to boot up. Going forward my goal is to get rid of mptables completely.

I have access to the ACPI data,however I need to parse and read these tables and generate a pseudo mptable so that the kernel doesn't have to undergo several changes.

The kernel currently gets its platform identification data from the mptable,so in an effort to minimize kernel/platform changes,this is my solution.

Are there suggestions or comments or something else I can do to make my task simpler ?

Thanks,
Rohit

Comment: Any takers out there ?

Comment: Help requested , please let me know